# Validate Swagger Validator Badge in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure pipelines, is there a way/task to validate the swagger API using the **Swagger Validator Badge**
https://github.com/swagger-api/validator-badge

Let me know how can I achieve this or is there any azure task that I can use.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check about below solution? How did it go?

Comment: Thanks, yes it did work, I need to still work on the validation part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script task to call the Swagger validator url. And then check the content length of the response. See below example in powershell task:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   
   $url ="http://validator.swagger.io/validator?url={YOUR_URL}"
   
   (curl $url).RawContentLength
```

If you want to fail the task when the  Swagger validator return a invalid badge. You can add few more scripts to fail the powershell task. Add below script to above task.

```
$length = (curl $url).RawContentLength 

if($length -ne 1599)
{  
    exit 1
}
```

If you want to to display the Badge on the Pipeline page. You can use a script task to write the image content into a file and then use [Publish HTML](https://github.com/farrellsoft/publish-html-task-extension) task to publish the badge to the build summary page. You need to [build this task and upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) to your devops organization. See below example:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
          
    Add-Content -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testhtml.html" -Value "<img src='http://validator.swagger.io/validator?url={YOUR_URL}'>"


- task: Farrellsoft.publish-html-task.publish-html-task.publishHtml@1
  displayName: 'Publish HTML'
  inputs:
    artifactName: swagger
    htmlFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\testhtml.html'
```

See below example result:

[image]